# Constructors and Prototypes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a very hard time learning Constructors and Prototypes. All I am trying to do is add 2 new objects to my construct and then display each part of the objects. In my example I would like to add the two object and the console log each name, address, and gpa.

constructor:

```
var Students = function(name, street, city, state, gpa) {
   this.student = {
      name: name,
      address: {
         street: street,
         city: city,
         state: state
      },
      gpa: gpa};
   this.array = [];
   this.array.push(this.student);
};

Students.prototype = {
   init: function(name, street, city, state, gpa) {
      this.student = {
         name: name,
         address: {
            street: street,
            city: city,
            state: state
         },
         gpa: gpa
      };
      this.array = [];
      this.array.push(this.student);
      console.log(this.array);
   },
   test: function() {
      console.log(this.array);
      for (i = 0; i < this.array.length; i++) {
         i = i % this.array.length;
         var studentTotal = 0;
         //This will loop through gpa array
         for (j = 0; j < this.array[i].gpa.length; j++) {
            studentTotal += this.array[i].gpa[j];
         }

         this.array[i].myAvg = studentTotal / this.array[i].gpa.length;
         this.array[i].gpaAverage = this.array[i].myAvg;
         console.log("Name: " + this.array[i].name);
         console.log("Address: " + this.array[i].address.street + ' ' +
                 this.array[i].address.city + ' ' +
                 this.array[i].address.state);
         console.log("GPA: " + this.array[i].gpa);
         console.log("Average: " + this.array[i].gpaAverage);
         console.log(new Date());
      }
   }
};
```

main.js :

```
var stud1 = [
   new Students(
           "Walker",
           '123 South Drive',
           'Sarasota',
           'FL',
           [
              3.0,
              3.4,
              3.8
           ]),
   new Students(
           'Christian',
           '5601 Pebble Beach Ln',
           'Sacromento',
           'CA', [
      2.5, 3.6, 3.8
   ])];

stud1.test();
```

Comment: And what's the issue?

Comment: Please describe exactly what problem you're having and what you would like help with.

Comment: When I run the stud1.test(); I come back with a syntax error stating that stud1.test(); is not a function

Comment: `stud1` is just an ordinary array.  It only has the methods of an array.

Answer (score 1):

You are constructing an array of students.

`var stud1 = [...]` is creating an array of `Students`  I'd imagine it would be more preferable to rename your `Students` function to `Student` (since it only constructs one student) and rename your array `stud1` to `studentArray` to make things more understandable.

Then, if you want to call `test()` on all the students in your array, use:

```
for(var i=0; i<studentArray.length; i++){
   studentArray[i].test();
}
```

In other works, you are trying to use the method `test()` on an array and arrays don't have that function, students do.

**EDIT:**

Considering your comment, you *could* make another object that can keep track of created students and serve as a factory for new students.  This encapsulates student creation logic and keeps listing all students out of the student construction logic and also gives you further insight into the construction of javascript objects.

Additionally, let your student be in charge of knowing their average GPA since you are already letting them keep track of their individual GPAs.  So add a function `getAverageGPA()` and then whenever you want to print the student out call the function `print()` which prints out all their information and gets their average GPA.

Since you want to do this every time you create a new student, have the Student Factory (`School`) do that for you.

**Student:**
The student class that holds all the information about the student and the functions to print him/her as well as get their average GPA.

```
/**
 * Student Object
 * @param {String} name
 * @param {String} street
 * @param {String} city
 * @param {String} state
 * @param {Array} gpa
 * @returns {Student}
 */
var Student = function(name, street, city, state, gpa) {
   this.name = name;
   this.address = {
      street: street,
      city: city,
      state: state
   };
   this.gpa = gpa;
};
Student.prototype = {
   /**
    * Function to print the student and their average GPA
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   print: function() {
      console.log("Name: " + this.name);
      console.log("Address: " +
              this.address.street + " " +
              this.address.city + " " +
              this.address.state);
      console.log("Average GPA: " + this.getAverageGPA());
   },
   /**
    * Function to find a students average GPA
    * @returns {Number}
    */
   getAverageGPA: function() {
      var avgGPA = 0;
      for (var j = 0; j < this.gpa.length; j++) {
         avgGPA = avgGPA + this.gpa[j];
      }
      avgGPA = avgGPA / this.gpa.length;
      return avgGPA;
   }
};
```

**School:**
The class that holds the students and is responsible for creating and printing them

```
/**
 * Object to encapsulate student creation while 
 * keeping track of all created students
 * @returns {School}
 */
function School() {
   /**
    * Array of all the students created so far
    * @type Array
    */
   this.createdStudents = [];
}
School.prototype = {
   /**
    * Function to add a student to the list of students
    * @param {Student} newStudent
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   addStudent: function(newStudent) {
      this.createdStudents.push(newStudent);
      this.printScores();
   },
   /**
    * Function to create a student, add it to the list, and return it
    * @param {String} name
    * @param {String} street
    * @param {String} city
    * @param {String} state
    * @param {Array} gpa
    * @returns {Student}
    */
   createStudent: function(name, street, city, state, gpa) {
      var newStudent = new Student(name, street, city, state, gpa);
      this.addStudent(newStudent);
      return newStudent;
   },
   /**
    * Print out all the students and their scores
    * @returns {undefined}
    */
   printScores: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.createdStudents.length; i++) {
         this.createdStudents[i].print();
      }
   }
};
```

**Main:**
What does the creation of the test students

```
/**
 * The Factory to hold students
 * @type School
 */
var school = new School();

// Student created yourself that you have access to in main
var standAloneStudent = new Student(
        "Bob",
        "555 Nowhere street",
        "Timbucktue",
        "AL",
        [
           4.0,
           4.0,
           4.0
        ]);

// You can get the students GPA without going through the factory
console.log("My student's GPA is: " + standAloneStudent.getAverageGPA());

console.log("");

// How to add a student that you create yourself
school.addStudent(new Student(
        'Christian',
        '5601 Pebble Beach Ln',
        'Sacromento',
        'CA',
        [
           2.5,
           3.6,
           3.8
        ]));

console.log("");

// How to create a student through the factory
school.createStudent(
        "Walker",
        '123 South Drive',
        'Sarasota',
        'FL',
        [
           3.0,
           3.4,
           3.8
        ]);

// You can also get the students GPA through the school 
// (However, you may want to make a set instead of an array so you can key
// off of a student's name or maybe ID)
console.log("My student's GPA is: " + school.createdStudents[0].getAverageGPA());
```

This should give you the output:

```
My student's GPA is: 4

Name: Christian
Address: 5601 Pebble Beach Ln Sacromento CA
Average GPA: 3.2999999999999994

Name: Christian
Address: 5601 Pebble Beach Ln Sacromento CA
Average GPA: 3.2999999999999994
Name: Walker
Address: 123 South Drive Sarasota FL
Average GPA: 3.4
My student's GPA is: 3.2999999999999994
```

Comment: How could I just add new objects and as the new object is created  console log all the objects, including the previously added objects?

Comment: So can I just get rid of my original object and use only this one?

Comment: I am trying to console log each individual part of the object. I want to be able to console log the name of each object, the address of each object ect.. This is where I get lost and don't know what to do.

Comment: You need to write a function to print out each variable of the `Student`.  I'll edit my answer to show you how.

Comment: Ok that would be great

Comment: Alright, this should explain to you what is going on with constructors and the like in JS.  Don't forget to accept the answer if it was helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much with being patient. That layout helps me alot understand objects.

Comment: How could I add more then on student at a time? Could I put the new Objects in an array?